Is there a way to display in the log whether tail sampling is sampling?
Our developers prefer a log-to-trace approach.
We use the W3C format and display trace-flags in the log to determine whether or not to sample.
When the trace was changed to be sampled through tail sampling, the log indicated that it had been sampled, but the actual trace was not sampled.
In this case, is there a way to make the log sampling results match the actual trace sampling results?
I want the log sampling and actual sampling to match.
